# Using a Regular Expression to Find Phone Numbers in all Files of a File Share

Tags: regex, file, phone-number, fileshare

I have another issue just whipping me.  I borrowed the following code (I can't recall from where) that looked super promising for determining phone numbers present in all files in a file share. The code absolutely makes sense to me, and that is why I am confused why it is not working. I test it with a document that I created in which I placed a phone number.  It returned nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse  | Select-String -pattern '^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}' | Select-Object -Unique Path) {$file.path}
```

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the file?

Comment: No. It provided nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that the

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}
```

regex requires the phone number to be first characters in a document (or a line) while in the actual documents it may be somewhere in the middle.

Change the `^` anchor to `\b` (word boundary). You may also want to add this word boundary anchor after the potential phone number:

```
\b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Comment: Ugh...no, it still didn't work. I am returning nothing at all.

Comment: Then provide a file sample, please.

Comment: Okay, so I got it to work.  The only problem now is that it ONLY picks up the .txt documents that contain the numbers.  I did it by testing for social security numbers this time:

Comment: here is what I used:   
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -filter | Select-String -pattern '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}' -allmatches | Select-Object -Unique Path) {$file.path}

Comment: So, I would like to know why it isn't picking up .docx which contains those numbers. Thanks for any help!